# Запросить по ip, указав при этом HOST

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Стоит задача получить страницу с сайта, войдя по ip, при этом указать HOST и путь страницы. Реализация нужна для Qt 5+ (так уж настроена сеть).

Answer (score 3):

Тут без обращения к DNS серверу не обойтись точно, именно на них храниится база сопоставления host: IP